# Parse post with comments

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Is there any example of parse.com Post with many comments ? or what method to use? like one to many relations on many to many relations , I have a Post and a Comment classes in my Parse data

Comment: https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create the comment
        ParseObject myComment = new ParseObject("Comment");
        myComment.put("content", txtComment.getText().toString());

// Add a relation between the Post with objectId ("1zEcyElZ80" for example) and //the comment
        myComment.put("parent", ParseObject.createWithoutData("Post", PostId));

// This will save both myPost and myComment
        myComment.saveInBackground();
     }
```

I solved the relation by getting the post id when pressing on it , thanks Kaiser for the comment , everything is explained there.